Scheduled query is being executed at a different and delayed time in PG_Cron
My use-case:
Run a query at a specific time daily using PG_Cron
My problem:
The expected output of running my Cron select cron.schedule('fifty-min', '50 * * * *', $$UPDATE sample_JSON2 SET is_active = FALSE WHERE createdon < CURRENT_DATE AND is_active IS TRUE;$$); is that it will run at 50th minute of every hour every day but the Cron gets executed at every 20th minute of every hour for some reason. This can be seen in the output of select * from cron.job_run_details;:
-[ RECORD 1 ]--+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
jobid          | 82
runid          | 375
job_pid        | 24774
database       | postgres
username       | postgres
command        | UPDATE sample_JSON2 SET is_active = FALSE WHERE createdon < CURRENT_DATE AND is_active IS TRUE;
status         | succeeded
return_message | UPDATE 1
start_time     | 2024-08-11 02:20:00.015661+05:30
end_time       | 2024-08-11 02:20:00.049399+05:30
-[ RECORD 2 ]--+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
jobid          | 82
runid          | 376
job_pid        | 25765
database       | postgres
username       | postgres
command        | UPDATE sample_JSON2 SET is_active = FALSE WHERE createdon < CURRENT_DATE AND is_active IS TRUE;
status         | succeeded
return_message | UPDATE 0
start_time     | 2024-08-11 03:20:00.009284+05:30
end_time       | 2024-08-11 03:20:00.040948+05:30

What I have done so far:
I have ensured that PG_Cron is using the correct timezone along with the prescribed configurations from the PG_Cron documentation in the postgresql.conf:
timezone = 'Asia/Kolkata' # My database's timezone
...
#cron.timezone = 'Asia/Kolkata'# Changed to IST to match document 
cron.timezone = 'IST' 
shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_cron'
cron.database_name = 'postgres'
cron.log_run = 'on'
...
cron.use_background_workers = on
max_worker_processes = 20               # (change requires restart)
cron.host = '/localhost'

My pg_hba.conf file has:
local   all             all                                     trust
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust

Where am I going wrong?

UPDATE:

I am using PG_Cron 1.4 & PostgreSQL 14
The output of running show timezone; & select '2024-08-11 7:50' at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'Asia/Kolkata';, respectively is:

-[ RECORD 1 ]----------
TimeZone | Asia/Kolkata

-[ RECORD 1 ]-----------------------
timezone | 2024-08-11 02:20:00+05:30


I did restart the PostgreSQL-server after timezone related modifications to config


Update 2
I have installed the latest version of PG_Cron but facing the same delay of 30 min in Cron job execution:
SELECT cron.schedule('testing', '21 * * * *', $$UPDATE sample_JSON2 SET is_active = FALSE WHERE createdon < CURRENT_DATE AND is_active IS TRUE;$$); # run at 21st minute of every hour

select * from cron.job_run_details ;
-[ RECORD 1 ]--+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
jobid          | 1
runid          | 4
job_pid        | 47895
database       | postgres
username       | postgres
command        | UPDATE sample_JSON2 SET is_active = FALSE WHERE createdon < CURRENT_DATE AND is_active IS TRUE;
status         | succeeded
return_message | UPDATE 0
start_time     | 2024-08-11 23:51:00.009017+05:30
end_time       | 2024-08-11 23:51:00.048235+05:30

How the latest version was installed:

Downloaded source code of version 1.6 from GitHub and extracted to ~/snap
sudo apt-get remove postgresql-14-cron
Added export PATH=/usr/pgsql-14/bin:$PATH to ~/.bashrc and sourced it
make && sudo PATH=$PATH make install
sudo systemctl restart postgresql


Final Update
How to schedule a job according to IST/specific timezone? Alternative is to convert your IST to UTC: Instead of 50 * * * *, do '20 * * * *' or use v1.5.


What version of  pg_cron? 2) Looks to me like UTC is still in the mix: show timezone; US/Pacific select '2024-08-11 7:50' at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'Asia/Kolkata'; 2024-08-11 02:20:00-07. Basically you are seeing the effect of the :30 offset. 3) did you restart the Postgres server after making the timezone change to the pg_cron file? ADD answers as text update to your question text.


Thanks for the response - I have added the answers to the post.

From pg_cron releases: v1.5.0  ... Adds a cron.timezone setting to configure the timezone of cron schedules, by @TsinghuaLucky912

Ah understood - I'll use a newer version of pg_cron in that case, thanks.

Have installed the latest version 1.6 after removing the previous one - Still facing the exact same issue of delay in cron-job execution, as explained in the updated post.


Have you verified that version 1.6 actually got loaded? In psql you can use \dx, otherwise do select extname, extversion from pg_extension where extname = 'pg_cron' 2) Look at the Postgres log when you restart the server to see if any relevant errors are being thrown.


Yes I have verified the version using \dx and have looked at the logs at debug level 1 but there aren't any error being thrown. The cron workers are started and cronjob is registered correctly and are being executed at UTC timezone instead of the configured IST.

I can't think of anything else, other then file an issue here pg_cron issues.

Actually one more thought I would use Asia/Kolkata for cron.timezone not IST as IST is not unique.

Thanks for everything, Adrian - You were of great help this entire time! This was actually the first thing that I did but when it didn't work, I switched to IST looking at how PRC was used to define timezone in the doc.
I went deep down into the GitHub page of PG_Cron and found that "configurable timezones" was a feature that was briefly added only into the v1.5 and then removed in the next versions due a compatibility issue - (Source in post).
The alternative for scheduling according to IST for now is:  Convert IST to UTC - '20 * * * *' (UTC ) instead of '50 * * * *'  (IST)

The compatibility issue you refer to is with Supabase and the issue was they had not updated to the 1.5+ version of pg_cron. I see nothing in the pg_cron code that shows it has been reverted.

Well in that case I'll continue with looking into why the cron.timezone is not working for me as expected even in the latest version and raise an issue as suggested.

I'm guessing because you are using IST. When you did the switch was when you where using pg_cron 1.4 and the timezone setting was ignored. As I suggested earlier change to cron.timezone = 'Asia/Kolkata' and see what happens.
